# Unable to retrieve the list of workspaces for Watson Conversation service

Tags: ibm-cloud, chatbot, watson-conversation

While launching tool for Watson Conversation Service, I get error:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm a developer working on the Watson Conversation Service. We delegate to Bluemix for permissions to edit Watson Conversation workspaces. In order to have permission to use the tooling on an instance of the Watson Conversation Service, you must have `developer` permissions in the Bluemix space in which the Conversation Service instance lives.